# Can't use submit() with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, forms, selenium

I have used `driver.find_element_by_id('SearchProductName')` to find the element with the following HTML:

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="SearchProductName" id="SearchProductName"
class="sg-input headerSearchBox ac_input" placeholder="Search for a 
product" tabindex="0">
```

It has recognised this element correctly and I have been able to `send_keys` to it, but when I try to `submit()`, I get the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 
Element was not in a form so couldn't submit
```

I don't understand how if the element is a textbox which I can `send_keys` to, it is not then a form which I can submit. How do I fix this problem so that I use submit on this element?

Comment: `<input>` elements can exist outside of forms. Can you not just simulate hitting enter? `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys; element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

Comment: is there a button you can click to "submit"? try clicking on this button instead of using submit method.

Answer (score 3):

`.submit()` is intended for controls that are inside of a `FORM`. It's a shortcut way to submit the form without clicking the Submit button. It looks like in your case the `INPUT` is not inside a `FORM` tag, thus the error message. I don't know what your page looks like but do with code what a user would do. The user fills out the input... what's their next step? Click a button or ? Do that with code and you should be able to progress in your scenario.